# How can i affect a single TimerButton to resend OTP in a lists builder with multiple TimerButton on flutter?

Tags: flutter

Am using timer_button package. the issue is there are possibilities where a user might have multiple transactions on his list so if he chooses to resend the otp for a particular transaction, all the other buttons also become disabled as well. How can i ensure that its only the clicked button that responds to the action?

```
TimerButton(
                                                        buttonType: ButtonType
                                                            .RaisedButton,
                                                        label: "Resend OTP",
                                                        timeOutInSeconds:
                                                            10,
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            ResendOTP(snapshot
                                                                .data[index]
                                                                .invoiceNumber);
                                                          });
                                                        },
                                                        disabledColor:
                                                            Colors.grey,
                                                        color: appbarColor,
                                                        disabledTextStyle:
                                                            new TextStyle(
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    15.0),
                                                        activeTextStyle:
                                                            new TextStyle(
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    15.0,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .white),
                                                      )
```